# Converting list error how to solved it? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compiler-errors

I wrote the program which subtracting items in list. The list needs to be converted from string to int or float.

I'm using this to convert list:

```
inputuserlist1 = input("  Type your numbers: ")
userlist = inputuserlist1.split()
userlist1 = list(map(int, userlist))
```

If the list is like ["1", "2"..."34"] the program works great but if it looks like ["d", "z"] my code has some error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Maksymalny Maks\programowanie\test.py", line 47, in <module>
    zadanie4b()
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Maksymalny Maks\programowanie\test.py", line 10, in zadanie4b
    userlist1 = list(map(int, userlist))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'w'
```

I'm trying to solve this problem but nothing wokrs proper. My bad solution:

```
import os
from typing import Literal
inputuserlist1 = input("  Type your numbers: ")
userlist = inputuserlist1.split()
while True:
    try:
        list(map(int, userlist)) = Literal
        ValueError(print("str"))
    except:
        userlist1 = list(map(int, userlist))
        break

print(userlist1)
os.system("pause")
```

Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
inputuserlist1 = input("  Type your numbers: ")
userlist = inputuserlist1.split()
for index,element in enumerate(userlist):
  if element.isnumeric():
    userlist[index] = int(element)
  else:
    del userlist[index]
print(userlist)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?